# Trying to rename a file upload as the hash of file content on wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, uploads

Trying to rename a file upload as the hash of file content on wordpress, not the file name as most tutorials are shown online. Which add_filter or how do I intercept the "content" of uploaded file so I can md5 it?

I would like the filename to be the md5 hash of the file content, for all sorts of file be it images or pdf or whatever.

Comment: Show some examples of what you have tried in code, so that users can comment and offer suggestions.

Comment: Hello, Frank, welcome to WPSE. Adding to what @Q Studio commented, I would suggest you to [add a little bit more of context, and information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to your question and explain what you already tried or strategies you might been thinking. Also, a little bit more context on your knowledge and skill with WordPress.